# A variety stratified by subvarieties defined over a smaller field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k\subset K$ be a field extension and let $X$ be a variety over $K$. Let $I$ be a set and let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a stratification on $X$. By this, I mean that each $X_i$ is a locally closed subvariety of $X$ such that $X = \bigsqcup_{i\in I} X_i$ and, if $\overline{X_i}$ denotes the closure of $X_i$ in $X$, then $X_j \cap \overline{X_i} \not = \emptyset \implies X_j \subset \overline{X_i}$ for all $i,j\in I$.

Assume that all the $X_i$'s are defined over $k$. Does it follow that $X$ is also defined over $k$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For instance, let $K \subset L$ be a field extension of degree $2$. Consider the quadric surface
$$
Q = \mathrm{Res}_{L/K}(\mathbb{P}^1_L)
$$
and the cone
$$
Y = \mathrm{Cone}(Q).
$$
Then over $L$ the cone $Y_L$ has two small resolutions of singularities, let $\pi \colon X \to Y_L$ be one of them. Then $X$ has a stratification $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2$, where
$$
X_2 = \pi^{-1}(Y_L \setminus \{y_0\})
\quad\text{and}\quad
X_1 = \pi^{-1}(y_0) \cong \mathbb{P}^1_L,
$$
where $y_0 \in Y_L$ is the vertex of the cone.
The strata are defined over $K$, but $X$ is not.

Comment: Thank you, very concrete and informative!